# Error in tr (translate characters) when storing string in variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

When using tr (translate characters) in a shell script, I get different results for using a string (correct result) and a string stored in a variable (error).

```
STRING="striNg"
echo "|$STRING|"
```

|striNg|

```
echo "striNg" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'
```

string

```
#Removing quotes around $STRING results in the same error
echo "$STRING" | tr'[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'
```

./test.sh: line 16: tr[:upper:]: command not found

```
echo "|$STRING|"
```

|striNg|

Comment: You need space between `tr` and `'[:upper:]'`. Error says so.

Comment: You are not showing the part of your code that is causing this error.  Although, I can't imagine what would remvoe the space in between the tr and the regex class for you.

Comment: @7171 Thank you for finding the error.

Comment: As an aside, you should avoid uppercase variable names, as they are reserved for system use.

Answer (score 0):

Answered by **@7171u**

Just for the question to close.

The fix on this problem was to leave a space between `tr` and `'[:upper:]'`.